# $G$, $|G|=n$ is nilpotent $\iff$ $\forall m|n$, $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Prove $G$, $|G|=n$ is nilpotent $\iff$ $\forall m|n$, $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $m$.
I got stuck in the second direction.

*One direction*: $|G|=n=p_1^{s_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_k^{s_k}$ Where $p_i$ prime. Particularly, $\forall p_i^{s_i}, p_i^{s_i}|n$ and therefore the *Sylow*-$p_i$ subgroup is unique and normal. Therefore every *Sylow*-$p$ subgroup is normal and that means $G$ is nilpotent. (There is a theorem\corollary claiming that saying every *Sylow*-$p$ subgroup is normal is equivalent to saying $G$ is nilpotent.

*Other direction*: Let $G$ be nilpotent. $|G|=n=p_1^{s_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_k1^{s_k}$ Where $p_i$ prime. Then, *Sylow*-$p_i$ subgroup is unique and normal. But what about the $p$-*subgroups* of order such as $p_i^{},p_i^{2},...,p_i^{s_i-1}$? They are subgroups contained in the *Sylow*-$p_i$ subgroup, and they all divide $n$, but are they normal? How can I show that?

Comment: Not all such subgroups are normal, but you only need to show that for every group $P$ of order $p^k$ (with $p$ prime), and every $j \le k$, $P$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^j$. You could do this by induction on $j$, using the fact that $Z(P) \ne 1$ for the base case $j=1$.

Comment: But then I have normal subgroups of a normal subgroup...

Comment: That might be a characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup, which makes a world of difference.

Comment: Is it necessarily normal in G?

Comment: Even outer automorphisms of $P$ map $Z(P)$ to itself.

Comment: I edited your post a bit. See the source for a different way of producing text in italics. The dollar-signs will occasionally produce funny spacing. Also, IMVHO Sylow is still spelled with an upper case S. If you feel like honoring him by using lower case, please let me know, and I will revert the edition to that extent :-)

Comment: Oh I am sorry. In Hebrew it has no spacial letter for there aren't any. Thank you for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: I still am not sure what I am to do here. 
We didn't learn much about automorphisms. Not to mention outer or inner :(

Comment: You don't need to worry about characteristic subgroups - that's a red herring! A finite nilpotent group is the direct product $P_1 \times \cdots \times P_k$ of its Sylow subgroups, so any normal subgroup of any $P_i$ is also normal in $G$.

Comment: How does it follow from the direct product? not that direct to me though :(

Comment: Sorry about leading you astray with that talk about characteristic subgroup. I was on autopilot. As Derek said (see also my comment under Timbuc's answer) you need to use the fact that a nilpotent group is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups. In a direct product a normal subgroup of a factor is a normal subgroup of the whole thing.

Comment: Is there a way to prove it formally? 
It's just that I never encountered such a theorem

Comment: It's an easy exercise that is left to the reader.

Comment: Okay.. maybe that's because I am weak when it comes to knowing the properties of a direct product...

Comment: Meitar, in an (inner) direct product of two subgroups $G=H\times K$ we have that 1) all the elements $g$ of $G$ can be uniquely written in the form $g=hk$ with $h\in H, k\in K$. AND 2) $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H, k\in K$. Now if you take a normal subgroup of $H$ and conjugate it with $g$,...

Comment: Why does $hk=kh$? That I didn't know..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

Since $\;G\;$ is nilpotent then every Sylow subgroup is normal. Now use the following:

Lemma 1: If $\;H\;$ is a finite $\;p$- group, $\;|H|=p^n\;$ , then for all $\;0\le k\le n\;$  there exists *a normal* subgroup $\;K\;$ of $\;H\;$ of order $\;p^k\;$

Proof (hints): use that $\;Z(H)\neq 1\;$, induction + the correspondence theorem (a subgroup of a quotient group is normal iff its inverse image under the quotient homomorphism is normal in the whole group)

Finally, as $\;G\;$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups and each pair of these commutes (why?) and etc.

Using the above (or whatever), you can also try the following nice

Lemma: The group $\;G\;$ is nilpotent iff $\;xy=yx\;$ for any pair of elements in the group *with coprime orders*.

Comment: Thank you :) 
The characteristic thing is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I'm afraid the argument in the end is false. The correct logic is: a characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is itself normal. You are saying: a normal subgroup of a characteristic subgroup is normal. This is not always true.

Comment: To fix things in the end you need to use the fact that a nilpotent is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups. In a direct product elements of various factors commute, so...

Comment: Yes the characteristic thing is problematic... 
I remember proving the lemma... I sweat blood

Comment: Not only it is false: it is even not true :) .I'm editing the answer, and thanks to Jirky.

Answer (score -1):

Observe that $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $G\cong P_{1}\times\cdots\times P_{n}$, a direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups. Thus the first result.

It is obvious that if $G$ is cyclic, then it has a unique subgroup of each order dividing $\left|G\right|$ (see Theorem~2.3.7(3)). On the other hand, suppose $G$ has a unique subgroup of each order dividing $\left|G\right|$. In particular, the Sylow $p$-subgroups are normal so $G$ is a direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups. Exercise~5.5.20 implies each component of the direct product is cyclic so $G$ is cyclic. Thus the result.

Comment: You are answering a completely different question. The queestion seeks to characterize nilpotent groups, not cyclic groups.